# show that if $n$ is not divisible by $3$ then $n^2 = 3m+1$ for some integer $m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Could someone please lend me some help on how to solve this problem?

I need help with proving this:

if $n$ is not divisible by $3$ then $n^2 = 3m+1$ for some integer $m$

Thanks!

Comment: In general, $n$ can be written as one of $3r-1,3r,3r+1$ for integer $r$ right?

Comment: If $n$ not divisible by $3$, then either $n=3k+1$ or $n=3l+2$.

Answer (score 3):

$n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)$. Since $n$ is not a multiple of $3$, then $n+1$ or $n-1$ must be multiple of $3$. Then $n^2-1$ is a multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 1):

If n
not divisible by 3, then either n=3k+1 or n=3l+2
now  lets square it
in first case $n^2$ = $(9k^2 + 6k + 1)$
                  = $3(3k^2 +2k) + 1$
                  = 3m +1
in second case 
                  = $9k^2$ + 12k + 4
                  = 3$(3k^2 +4k+1)$ + 1
                  = 3m + 1

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

For such small cases what I'm about to do is overkill, but if you're interested in modular arithmetic these are things you'll need to know

Fermat's Little theorem states that for every number $a$ not divisible by a prime $p$, $ a^{p-1} - 1 $ is divisible by $p$

In this case, since $3$ is a prime, for every $a$ not divisible by $3$, $a^{3-1} = a^2 = 3m + 1 $ for some integer $m$, because $(3m + 1) - 1= 3m $ which is divisible by 3

Even more overkill is using Euler's totient function: $a^{\varphi(n)} = bn +1$ for some integer $b$ when a is relatively prime to n, and where $\varphi (n)$ counts all the positive integers between 1 and n that are relatively prime to n

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that reaminders of $n$ divided $3$ are $1$ or $2$.

Then we want to show that  $n^2=3m+1$ i.e., $n^2+2=3m+3=3(m+1)$.

Now we must show that 3 divisible by $n^2+2$. the remainder of $n^2$ divided $3$ is just $1$.Thus $3\mid n^2+2$.